# Android NDK - 'extern' functions in library not found when app starts

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, shared, extern

I have built my Shared Library using NDK, that has few other libs in it. My lib has few 'extern' function defined. As it is a lib, those 'extern' functions are then declared in project (.cpp) file. I have an issue, where application *builds just fine*, and crashes on the device with the following error:

**07-12 00:45:03.680: E/dalvikvm(2161): dlopen("/data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-16/libRTEngine.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "RTEngineSetup" referenced by "libRTEngine.so"...**

This RTEngineSetup function is defined in my lib as : **extern "C" void RTEngineSetup();**
And then my application declares it like: **void RTEngineSetup() { ... }**

It seems like it can't link them together. This system works just fine on Desktops.

Here is an image of my code design: 
http://s14.postimg.org/s0r83u801/my_code.png

Here is how I build my libs (first part) and my Application (that includes my libs) (second part):
http://ann-tech.com/lib_Android.txt

Please, if anyone has any idea why 'extern' definition () is not linked with it's declaration in application's .cpp file, please let me know. Wasted 2 days now.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex!

This is amazing! thank you very much. I am new to NDK and Android coding so had to hack for 3 days straight. When you said to use dlsym(), I had no idea what i it is. But I have figured it out and everything works just perfect now.

Solution:
If your Library has C++ functions (defined) as **extern** - *extern void Update();* for example,
and you are trying to link this library to your application, where you want to (declare) those functions like that: void Update() { ... }, you have to, in your library C++ code, add this code:

```
//Library file pointer
void *handle;
handle = dlopen( "lib/libRTApp.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY );

// New names for functions you are linking to
void ( *RTUpdate )( void ), ( *RTClose )( void );

// Assigning function to a pointer
*( void ** ) ( &RTUpdate ) = dlsym( handle, "RTAppUpdate" );
*( void ** ) ( &RTClose ) = dlsym( handle, "RTAppClose" );

// Free the memory!
dlclose( handle );
```

Thanks a lot **Alex Cohn**! You have saved me.

Comment: I believe that you don't need `dlopen()`, but `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, name)` is enough. Would you like to verify?

Comment: Yes Alex, you are right. This is even easier then :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't allow `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS` in your Android.mk. Then your problem will be visible at link step.

Which **.cpp** file defines the **RTEngineSetup**? Does it include the header file that declares it as **extern "C"**?

In NDK toolchain there is **nm** utility which can show the list of symbols that are defined in each **.so**, and also external references.

Unfortunately, the Android dynamic loader cannot resolve circular dependencies. You can split libRTApp in two parts (one which only provides `RTEngineSetup()` and her kin for `libRTEngine.so` to link, the other - that depends on `RTEngine` and all other libs), or use  `dlsym()` in `libRTEngine` to find the references to RTEngineSetup()` and her kin at run time, e.g.

```
pRTEngineSetup = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "RTEngineSetup");
```

.. and so on

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This structure works on other platforms just fine.

Libs ==> MyEngine (has 5 extern "C" definitions) ==> Application (uses MyEngine and declares those 5 extern funcs)

If I don't use LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS while building a MyEngine lib, I get following errors:

http://pastebin.com/rfmqB5cJ

If I use that flag set to true, it builds MyEngine Lib, and builds the application using this Lib, but then says that my extern "C" funcs are not declared anywhere, even though they are in my Application, that uses this lib. Any idea?

Comment: Here is another image, hopefully explaining better what I do: http://s14.postimg.org/4t3vl5ds1/my_stuff.png The problem is, that it seems that my Engine is not build like a Lib (On NDK), otherwise it would know that some of it's funcs are Declared outside of it.

Comment: So, `RTEngineSetup` and others are exported from `libRTApp.so`? You should link `libRTEngine.so` after `libRTApp.so`. The dependencies are controled by `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: You _may_ find the [crazy linker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/sources/android/crazy_linker/README.TXT) useful.

Comment: I have tried all of the basics in last 2 days. Nothing works. I have libRTApp linked before libRTEngine.so. Ok. Thanks for the attempt. Will keep looking/hacking.

Comment: I understand that you are desperate. But what happened when you linked libRTApp before libRTEngine? Are there undefiwreferences? Note that in Java, you also have to change the order of `System.loadLibrary()` calls. But nothing will help if you have _circular dependency_ between RTApp and RTEngine, except `dlopen()`

Comment: In both cases, application compiles, runs, but crashes with the same issue: It cant figure out, that [extern "C" void RTEngineStup();] that is DEFINED in the lib, is then DECLARED in App.cpp as [void RTEngineSetup { ... }]. On Desktop platforms, it works, as I use Visual Studio/CodeBlocks, and when building the Library, I tell the compiler that it is a Library and it will not complain about my 5 functions that are marked as 'extern'.

Comment: Then when I link this lib to my application, the compiler just knows, that all those 5 funcs, that are DEFINED in my lib (but not DECLARED), are DECLARED in the app.cpp file that includes it. And it just works. I think I am missing some flag or something when I am building my Engine shared lib, to let ndk-build know, that it is a Lib and that 'extern' funcs/variables will be declared in app.cpp, that includes this lib.